# Prove this modification of the Ratio Test for Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is a series such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=r$.  If  $r<1$, then the series converges.

Comment: Can you prove the case where $a_{n+1}/a_n=r$ for all $n$?

Comment: no, I am stuck on where I would begin with that

Comment: How about the case where $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}/a_n=1/2$ for all $n$?

Comment: How is that even possible?

Comment: Easily.${}{}{}$

Comment: could you show me?

Comment: Sure, but instead I'll let you *think* about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $s\in(r,1)$. For $n\geq N$ you have $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<s$. Now apply the standard Ratio Test to the series $\sum\limits_{n=N}^\infty a_n$.